# Python3 SyntaxError with asyncpg

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, syntax-error, asyncpg

I am trying to create a connection pool as shown on [the documentation](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#connection-pools) to test the module.

**Here's my last attempt:**

```
import asyncpg
cs = "user:password@my_postgresql_server_ipaddr:port/database?name=db_name"

async with asyncpg.create_pool(dsn=cs) as pool:
    print("pool created")
```

**I'm getting a SyntaxError on line 4, pointing at 'with':**

```
async with asyncpg.create_pool(dsn=cs) as pool:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Running the code from the Python interpreter on the terminal produces the same results.

Python version is 3.6.5, running the script from the terminal with `python3 script.py`

Comment: Can you try without `async with` ?

Comment: Seems to be working, but am I not missing out on the async part this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should wrap your code inside an `async` function and call it inside loop , for example:

```
import asyncio
import asyncpg

async def test():
    cs = "user:password@my_postgresql_server_ipaddr:port/database?name=db_name"
    async with asyncpg.create_pool(dsn=cs) as pool:
        print("pool created")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
    loop.close()
```

more details: [example-chain-coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#example-chain-coroutines)

Comment: Thank you! It also looks like I need to fix my connection string.

Comment: glad to help you)